# Swift mocking NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to mock NSUserDefaults in Swift to be able to create tests on classes that use the NSUserDefaults. Now I run into a problem because the Proxy has no public initializer and I cannot overwrite it. I cannot use the regular proxy either because its initializer is private and cannot be used outside the scope of the nesting class.

Any ideas how to solve this? Any neat tricks that could help me to initialize the FakeProxy?

```
public class FakeProxy : NSUserDefaults.Proxy {
    private let defaults: NSUserDefaults
    private let key: String

    public init(_ defaults: NSUserDefaults, _ key: String) {
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.key = key
        // Problem: Super.init isn't called before returning from initializer
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement FakeProxy in Objective-C and bridge it over to Swift in order to get around Swift being over-protective here.

Alternatively, perhaps instead of your main code using an NSUserDefaults type, it could use a protocol type that your FakeProxy implements, and then also [extend NSUserDefaults to implement the protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID277) as well, and then swap them out via the protocol type.